# html script tag source not loading

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript, and need some help. I have certain html code. I have certain javascript that sets the attribute of img to x. But the problem is I can't properly load the page without internet connection, since script is stored on the internet.
I had an idea. I created a script, which will change sources depending on the fact whether the variable is defined or not. Here it is:

```
function scriptsrc(){ 
    if (typeof imgsrc != 'undefined'){
        document.getElementsByTagName('script') [0].setAttribute('src', 'xxx');
    } else {
        document.getElementsByTagName('script') [0].setAttribute('src', 'blob:null/xxx');
    }
}
```

This works fine. However, I am troubled with `'blob:null/xxx'` source.

When I have no internet connection I can access this resource if i just put it in search bar. When I use it as `<script>` source, the function defined in script is not defined. I think my browser (Firefox) just doesn't load that script.

How do I do it so that Firefox can load this script source?

Comment: Why'd you tag this Java? JavaScript is not Java.

Comment: ummm...is this really tagged as java?i chose the only tag,and it is javascript.i chose java as something i am interested in in profile,so maybe it popped up because of that reason.

Comment: It was tagged as Java (see http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41782296/revisions). I changed it to JS.

Comment: oh,really?okay,thanks